# Check whether data returned from php via ajax is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried (data = "") and various others but none seem to work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/peopleGoingList.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {"ID": eventID},
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);

    if (data.length === 0) {
        $("#dialog-attendees").html("<p>No one is going.. :[</p>");
    } else {
        $("#dialog-attendees").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I always return JSON with `['ok']` set to true if everything went well and check `if (typeof data=='object' && data.ok)`

Comment: I originally returned json but I want sure how to loop though all the json data so I decided to echo html data in the php file instead. Musa's answer worked so I will stick with it :)

Comment: Ok but FYI `$json=array('ok'=>true, 'html'=>$thehtml); echo json_encode($json); die;` and `$("#dialog-attendees").html(data.html);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably arbitrary white space in your output, try trimming it

```
if ($.trim(data) == '') {
```